# Adding space in ToC between the part number and part title

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, memoir, parts

I am running into some formatting trouble with memoir and the `\part` commands. In the table of contents, as the number of parts add up, the space between the part number, i.e. "III" and the part heading, i.e. "Background", gets smaller.

Is there a way of adding a constant space there, so that each part title are separated from the part number by the same amount? Here's an MWE showing the problem.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \part{Background}

    \chapter{The problem}

    \chapter{Risk assessment}

    \part{Theory and principles}

    \chapter{Inductively coupled plasma mass spectrometry}

    \chapter{Inductively coupled plasma optical emission spectrometry}

    \chapter{X-ray diffraction}

    \chapter{Ion chromatography}

    \part{Thesis}

    \chapter{Introduction}

    \chapter{Methodology}

    \chapter{Results}

    \chapter{Discussion}

    \chapter{Conclusion}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's possible to do this with `tocloft`

Comment: Add `\renewcommand\partnumberlinebox[2]{#2\hspace{1em}}` to your preamble and replace `1em` with the distance of your coosing.

Comment: Or adjust the width of the box so the part titles also line up as the chapter titles does on `DG'`'s example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [memoir manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) says on page 156 that

> the \book, \part and \chapter numbers are typeset inside a box of certain fixed withs

In order to get a fixed width after the part number, we have to get rid of the box and insert some whitespace (1em in this example) after the number. We do so by renewing `\partnumberlinebox`:

```
\renewcommand\partnumberlinebox[2]{#2\hspace{1em}}
```

Now the MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand\partnumberlinebox[2]{#2\hspace{1em}} % <-- Adds 1em whitespace between part number and title

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \part{Background}

    \chapter{The problem}

    \chapter{Risk assessment}

    \part{Theory and principles}

    \chapter{Inductively coupled plasma mass spectrometry}

    \chapter{Inductively coupled plasma optical emission spectrometry}

    \chapter{X-ray diffraction}

    \chapter{Ion chromatography}

    \part{Thesis}

    \chapter{Introduction}

    \chapter{Methodology}

    \chapter{Results}

    \chapter{Discussion}

    \chapter{Conclusion}


\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]